# How do I query MongoDB to find all records which contain a particular array of objects?

Tags: mongodb-query

I am implementing tagging functionality in my Angular MEAN stack app and so want to query the DB to retrieve all objects (in this case "NFR"s) which have one or more of those tags ("Tag" objects). Thus I have NFR objects which may contain an array of Tag objects. I have tried a number of MongoDB find queries which return nothing despite tagged records existing.
Here are some code snippets (Mongoose schema defs for NFR and Tag). Thanks very muchly in advance :-).
Katie

- NFR schema:

  ```
  import * as mongoose  from "mongoose";
  import {Tag} from "../../app/main/models/tag";

  let NFR = new mongoose.Schema({
       category: String,
       subCategory: String,
       nfr: String,
       acceptanceTest: String,
       source: String,
       status: String,
       creationDate: Date,
       createdBy: String,
       changeLog: String,
       tags: [{
           type: Tag
       }]
  });
  ```
- Tag schema

  ```
  import * as mongoose  from "mongoose";

  let Tag = new mongoose.Schema({
       name: String,
       source: String,
       creationDate: Date,
       _id: String
  });
  ```

In the database the NFR object to search on contains two Tag objects via object id reference [image: screenshot of database].

Comment: Can you add one of your attempts ? Just wanted to see the input data and query you use

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Veeram, I had to move the Tag mongoose class inside the NFR one to get it creating the associated Tag object properly (which I can now search on). This is a bad hack, not sure why it doesn't work the proper way but it will do for now.